# Formalities about the expectation random variable

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, expectation

Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of non-negative random variables, so all $\mathbb{E}[X_n]\leq \infty$ are well-defined. Then $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ is a well-defined random variables as well (why?), non-negative and by Beppo-Levi and the linearity of integrals, we have that
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}\big[\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n\big] = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}[ X_n ].
\end{align}
Moreover, I am wondering why $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\mathbb{E}[ X_n ] < \infty $ implies that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n < \infty $ a.s.?

Comment: Well, if $P\{X=\infty\}>0$, then $E[X]=\infty$.

Comment: $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n$ is measurable as a limit of measurable functions.

Comment: For all $\omega \in \Omega$, the sequence $S_n(\omega):=\sum_{k=1}^n X_n(\omega)$ is non decreasing and therefore its limit (denoted by S), which could be finite or infinity, is well defined. The Beppo-Levi theorem tells you that $E[S]=\sum_n E[X_n]$, which is true regardless if the expaction is finite or not. Finally, if the random variable S has finite expectation, then it is finite (as Zoran pointed out in the first comment, you can use contradiction).

Comment: For the last statement, does it hold that $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{E}[X_n] = \mathbb{E}[ \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n] < \infty$$ \implies \int \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n\ d\mathbb{P} < \infty $$\implies \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n \in \mathcal{L}^1$$ \implies \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} |X_n| $$= \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} X_n < \infty$, since integrability implies finiteness?